# arch_vma_name undefined kernel module

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am getting following error when i try to insert a module

```
insmod: error inserting 'memory.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module
```

Following happens when i make the module

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/work modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64'
    Building modules, stage 2.
    MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "arch_vma_name" [/work/memory.ko] undefined!
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64'
```

You can see the reason of the error is arch_vma_name

Here is chunk of code where i used it

```
const char *name = arch_vma_name(vma);
```

I have included the header file

```
#include <linux/mm.h>
```

I am not able to understand the reason.

Comment: Is `arch_vma_name()` exported by the kernel? If it is not, this could be the reason.

Comment: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.28.1/fs/proc/task_mmu.c#L234

Here is a kernel code which uses the same function. I have the same kernel version.

Comment: This code is from the kernel proper rather than from a kernel module. The global symbols that are not exported are available for the kernel but not for the modules.

Comment: Yeah you might be wright their is no grep for __ksymtab_arch_vma_name in /proc/kallsyms file.
Anyway thanks for the help